# my ec2 linux is not connect to the internet?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, firewall

when I ran `$ git clone https://github.com/aliscie/autodox` it took too long to respond to this command and then it shows `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<whatever>': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out`. Also, when I tried `sudo yum install docker` I got the same issue but different error message

```
https://amazonlinux-2-repos-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2/extras/docker/stable/x86_64/9273ea3ff10ea479755a952f9b7816de5808a0
9ab6d2cf7c7f56ea422962d7ac/repodata/repomd.xml?instance_id=i-0baa228b430689a3b&region=eu-west-1: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://amazon
linux-2-repos-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2/extras/docker/stable/x86_64/9273ea3ff10ea479755a952f9b7816de5808a09ab6d2cf7c7f56
ea422962d7ac/repodata/repomd.xml?instance_id=i-0baa228b430689a3b&region=eu-west-1: (28, 'Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds
')
Trying other mirror.
```

- I tried

1. `aws configure` but I did not provide `AWS Access Key ID` because I don't
2. I tried to flow the article [Troubleshoot EC2 instance internet gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-connect-internet-gateway/) but it was useless for me
3. in `security groups` I setted Inbound and Outbound rules to allow all trafices anywhere.

Comment: From the instance, can you access a website, eg `curl google.com`? That will test whether the instance has Internet access.

Comment: I ran that and it took too long then it returned `curl: (28) Failed to connect to google.com port 80: Connection timed out`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein do you know why it says port `80` while it says `443` when I ran `git clone...`?

Comment: HTTP uses port 80. HTTPS uses port 443. The fact that you can login to the EC2 instance indicates that your Inbound security group rules are fine. The problem would lie either with the Security Group Outbound rules, or Network ACLs (if you modified them) or with a firewall configured within the instance's operating system.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you so much, I checked my network ACls in vpc, and I added new rules to allow all traffic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, **Security groups** should be configured with:

- Inbound rules that permit access to the desired ports (eg port 80 for HTTP, port 443 for HTTPS, port 22 for SSH) from as few IP addresses as possible. For example, HTTP would be open to the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`) but while SSH should be open only to *your* IP address
- Outbound rules that "Allow All" outbound access because you can typically trust what is running on your own instance

In general, **Network Access Control Lists (NACLS) should never be changed** from their default "Allow All" state unless you have a very specific networking requirement (eg creating a DMZ). Security Groups are sufficient for controlling access.